# code coverage for other than RunTimeException is not covering

Tags: java, junit, code-coverage

Am writting Junit code coverage for the below java code and the code is not covering for `Otherthan Runtime Exception`.

Please find my below java code.

```
public class NotifySupervisorJobTask implements Tasklet {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NotifySupervisorJobTask.class);

    @Autowired
    private CoreClient client;

    @Autowired
    private ItemProcessFailedNotifier itemProcessFailedNotifier;

    @Override
      public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) {
        try {
            client.notifySupervisor(null);
            LOGGER.info("notifySupervisorJobTask - execute() called");        
        } catch (RuntimeException exception) {
          String errorMessage = format("Error in triggering notify supervisor job. Task will be repeated at next scheduled time. Error is: [%s]", exception.getMessage());
          LOGGER.error(errorMessage, exception);
          contribution.setExitStatus(FAILED);
          itemProcessFailedNotifier.notifyByEmailOnException(chunkContext.getStepContext(), new Exception(errorMessage,
              exception));

        }
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
      }

}
```

Please find my `testcase` code for `other than runtime exception` case.

@InjectMocks 
    private NotifySupervisorJobTask notifySupervisorJobTask;

```
@Mock
private ItemProcessFailedNotifier itemProcessFailedNotifier;

@Mock
private CoreClient client;

private ChunkContext chunkContext;

private StepContext stepContext;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    chunkContext = mock(ChunkContext.class);
    stepContext = mock(StepContext.class);
    when(chunkContext.getStepContext()).thenReturn(stepContext);
}

@Test(expected = Exception.class)
 public void shouldThrowExceptionOtherThanRuntimeException() throws Exception {
    Exception ex = mock(Exception.class);
    doThrow(ex).when(client).notifySupervisor(null); // Line not covered
    notifySupervisorJobTask.execute(null, chunkContext); // Line not covered
    verify(itemProcessFailedNotifier).notifyByEmailOnException(stepContext, ex); // Line not covered
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't tell Mockito to throw an exception which can't possibly be thrown by the mocked method.

In Java, you have checked and unchecked exceptions. Unchecked in your case are subclasses of `RuntimeException`. Checked are all others (including the `Exception` class itself), but they have to be either catched, or declared in the surrounding method signature.

Since your `notifySupervisor` method obviously doesn't declare any checked exceptions (otherwise your `execute` method wouldn't compile), Mockito can't go against the compiler and throw such an exception from its mock.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. My code covered 100% now. :)